# Expected initializer before NOEXCEPT

Tags: c++

I am facing an error of expected initializer before noexcept and I'm running this code on windows 10.

I've tried adding braces but of no use I was not able carve out solution to my problem.

```
const static std::vector<std::pair<StatusCode, std::string> > status_codes()       
  noexcept
{
 const static std::vector<std::pair<StatusCode, std::string> > status_codes = {
    } 
}
```

[Error] expected initializer before 'noexcept'
[Error] expected '}' at end of input

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem by [setting gcc into C++03 mode](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s4ChcT). Your compiler is designed for an older version of C++. `noexcept` requires C++11.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always check your code for syntax before asking questions. Also I seems you should consult more of C++ literature, since it seems you need to grasp more the basics. For example I assume you want to return a reference to a const vector out of the static function. Otherwise wound't have to make a static vector inside of your function, which you copy from every time, when returning a full new vector instance. (Otherwise never return reference to automatic i.e. non static function variables)

Comment: Raymond Chen I took that for granted and thought its just because of his illformed syntax. Still not only noexcept here needs C++11.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a semicolon after the static vector definition:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using StatusCode = int;

const static std::vector<std::pair<StatusCode, std::string> > status_codes()
  noexcept
{
 const static std::vector<std::pair<StatusCode, std::string> > status_codes = {
    };
 return status_codes;
}
```

Don't forget to always return something out of non void functions

Also don't that you need at least **C++11** or higher compatible compilers in order to compile your code.